# Access text generated with javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, webclient, wget

This website has a custom google search box:

http://ezinearticles.com/

The search results are generated by a piece of JS code. How would I access these results using wget and/or C#'s `WebClient`?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the searches on that page are normal google site searches. Try wget with the following url, where 'asdf' is your search

```
wget http://www.google.com/search?&q=site:ezinearticles.com+asdf
```

Comment: Based on my sample search for 'writing', it seems that it is not the case here.

Comment: You could always wget the ezinearticles.com search page directly if the result sets are different when going straight to google.

Answer (score 0):

You need to to what your web browser does - render the page. Maybe you can extract the js call to the webservice providing the results and just execute this request and parse the output directly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access it with a programmable browser supporting JavaScript.

- The [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) library for Java does this, and runs fine headless.
- You can automate a real web browser, e.g. with [WatiN](http://watin.org/) on Windows, and access the page's content. This requires a GUI desktop though, because a real browser window is opened.